# how to combine multiple orion entities to one ckan dataset using cygnus?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, ckan, fiware-cygnus

Right now I'm trying to create a dataset for my orion data with all the entitys info. 
I set up all correctly and when some data changes orion send a notification to cygnus and then, cygnus will add the data to ckan. 
As seen in this image.

[image: My arquitecture]

The problem is that cygnus create a ckan resource for each entity. 
What could I do to make cygnus put all data in only one resource?
Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

I just found that I can simplify by making just one subscription in orion.

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Room",
            "isPattern": "true",
            "id": "Room.*"
        }
    ] ...
```

Then I noticed the grouping feature ([http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installation_and_administration_guide/grouping_rules_conf/index.html](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installation_and_administration_guide/grouping_rules_conf/index.html=)) in cygnus but right now I'm lost because cygnus don't want to load my grouping config file. It shows this error:

```
time=2016-05-03T05:32:29.658CDT | lvl=INFO | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | function=<init> | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingRules[58] : No grouping rules have been read
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$ConfigurationReader.run(GroupingInterceptor.java:244)
```

In my agent config file I have:

```
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.gropuing_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf
```

And in grouping_rules.conf:

```
{
    "grouping_rules": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fields": [
                "entityId"
            ],
            "regex": "room.*",
            "destination": "Rooms",
            "fiware_service_path": "/myhouse"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Edit 2:**

I have all the lines as documentation said:

```
    cygnusagent.sources = http-source
    cygnusagent.sinks = ckan-sink
    cygnusagent.channels = ckan-channel

    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = ckan-channel
    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = test
    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /myhouse
    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 5
    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
    cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.gropuing_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.type = memory
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnusagent.channels.ckan-channel.transactionCapacity = 100

# ============================================
# OrionCKANSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.channel = ckan-channel

# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionCKANSink

# true if the grouping feature is enabled for this sink, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.enable_grouping = true

# true if lower case is wanted to forced in all the element names, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.enable_lowercase = false

# the CKAN API key to use
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.api_key = 436fffc8-b397-478a-92fd-bbc5ffaf8269

# the FQDN/IP address for the CKAN API endpoint
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_host = ckan-demo.ckan.io

# the port for the CKAN API endpoint
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_port = 80

# Orion URL used to compose the resource URL with the convenience operation URL to query it
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.orion_url = http://localhost:1026

# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.attr_persistence = column

# enable SSL for secure Http transportation; 'true' or 'false'
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ssl = false

# number of notifications to be included within a processing batch
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_size = 100

# timeout for batch accumulation
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_timeout = 60

# number of retries upon persistence error
cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_ttl = 10
```

The file rights seems ok to me:

```
[root@VM013cen-Prod conf]# ls *.conf -l
-rwxrwxrwx 1 cygnus cygnus 2675 may  3 06:45 agent_test.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 cygnus cygnus  258 may  3 05:08 grouping_rules.conf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cygnus cygnus  135 mar  1 02:50 krb5_login.conf
```

The test pases ok:

```
Results :

Tests run: 80, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1:05.862s
    [INFO] Finished at: Tue May 03 06:53:44 CDT 2016
    [INFO] Final Memory: 41M/105M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The startup command i use: `/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_test.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, Grouping Rules are designed for achieving use cases as the one you are describing. So, by defining a simple rule with a regex matching the type of all the entities (assuming such a type is always the same) should do the trick; or by using a regex matching a common part of the entity ID (as you propose).

Nevertheless, your problem seems to be with the Grouping Rules read themselves. You say your configuration contains:

```
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.gropuing_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf
```

Can you confirm before that line you have something like this?

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
```

In addition, can you check the permissions of `/usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf`? Maybe it cannot be read by the user running Cygnus.

Regarding the rule, the new FIWARE service path should start with `/`, since all the FIWARE service paths must start with slash (I think this is not properly documented in the last version).

HTH!

**EDIT 1**:

I think I've found the problem. The configured parameter name is "...gro***p***uing...", while the correct one is "...grouping..." :)

Comment: I edited the question with more info. I also changed the service path adding the /. The problem persist don't know why. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Which version of Cygnus are yoy running? Can you add a pastebin with all the logs of a Cygnus run, please? I'm interested in the traces written from the start of the process.

Comment: OMG! I'm such an idiot. Thanks you so much. Please correct it in the doc so other people don get confused to. Here is the url http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start_guide/index.html#configuring-a-test-agent were i get the wrong config.

Comment: Not your fault, but mine :) I'll fix the doc.